# What are the different logging levels in Magento?

Tags: ce-1.6.2.0, log

I am disabling logging to increase performance, and in `core_config_data` I see `dev/log/active` and `system/log/active`

What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration system/log/active is related to logging in system.log and dev/log/active is related to debug/development log normally used with `SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true"`

References [here](http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/configuring-magento-for-development-debug-mode/).

Comment: Thank you.  Does disabling the system log also disable the exception reporting?  Or is that in the dev log?

Comment: From what I read, exception is on the dev log.